# How to deal with conditioned based validation in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a situation and unfortunately not sure how to sort it out in proper way. I have below script

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    $request->all(), 
    [
        'game_id' => 'required|integer'
    ],
    $messages
);

if ($validator->fails()) {    
    $response = $validator->messages();
}else{
    $response = $gameService->setStatus($request);
}
```

Now each game has different type, I wanted to add validation on behalf of type. For example if a game is `Task Based` then I would add validation for `time` which would be mandatory only for Task based game otherwise it would be an optional for other types.

I have three types of games

1 - level_based
2 - task_based
3 - time_based

In the type table, each game has type.

So is there any way to add validation?  I want to do it, inside validation function.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your conditions before the validation.

```
$data = $request->all();
if ($data['game_id'] == 1) {
    $rules = [
        // level_based validation
    ];
} else if($data['game_id'] == 2) {
    $rules = [
        // task_based validation
    ];
} else {
    $rules = [
        // time_based validation
    ];
}
$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
```

Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: Maybe a switch case is cleaner in this case?

Comment: Yup. In this case switch case would be much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the [required_if](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-required-if) validation rule.

So in your case, will send two fields, the type can be a hidden field for example, then on the `game_id` you will add

```
'game_id' => 'required_if:type,1'
```

and so on.. And of course you can customize the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class CreateGameRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }


    public function rules()
    {
        try {

            $request    = $this->request->all();
            $rule_array = collect();
            $rule1 =   [
                'game_id' => 'required|integer'
            ]
            $rule_array = $rule_array->merge($rule1);

            if(isset($request->task_id))
            {
                $rule2 =   [
                    'task_id' => 'required|integer'
                ]
            }

            $rule_array = $rule_array->merge($rule2);
            return $rule_array->all();

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e;
        }
    }



    public function messages(){

        return [
            'game_id' => 'Please select valid game',
            'task_id' => 'Please select valid task'            
        ];

    }
}
```

then invoke this request class in controller function as

```
use App\Http\Requests\CreateGameRequest;

public function game(CreateGameRequest $request)
{

}
```